# How to add a link in the footer similar to free blogger templates

Tags: javascript, blogger

I have seen footer links to template owner page on Blogger blogs. And if I try to remove or hide the link by editing the HTML content. It is not possible and the site will be redirected to their website. I know this is done by javascript. Can somebody help me how to do this?

```
<div class="copyright-area">Template by <a href="http://www.example.com/" id="mycontent" >some name</a></div>
```

The above code is an example. And if I add any modification to the above code, it will redirect to their website. Can anyone show me how to do this in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
// Check if href is changed
if ($("#mycontent").attr("href") != "https://www.example.com") {
 window.location.href = "https://www.example.com"; // Redirect destination link
};
    
// Check if tag is hidden
if ($("#mycontent").css('display') == 'none' || $("#mycontent").css("visibility") == "hidden"){
 window.location.href = "https://www.example.com"; // Redirect destination link
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href='https://www.example.com' id='mycontent'>Credit Link</a>
```

You will be redirected to destination link if `#mycontent`'s `href` changed, not displayed, or it's visibility set to hidden.

Comment: Hey, what if the  'Credit Link' text is changed, how can I prevent it using js?